# Mongodb- some value missing until update the document on shell

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java to operate mongodb.

when i queried, find some value is missing.but when i update the document on shell,

```
var dataList = db.last.find({"date":"2016-03-09"});
    for(var i = 0;i < dataList.length();i++){
        var data = dataList[i];   //do nothing with it
        db.last.update({"_id":data._id},data);
    }
```

and then queried,the result is normal.
the document in mongodb like that

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("56df0865d23b548768ae4256"),
      "uniq_key" : "last:HIS_AI:13:20:2016-3-9",
      "type" : "last",
      "date" : "2016-03-09",
      "channel_id" : "13",
      "no_ai" : "20",
      "zset" : [{
          "hour" : "0",
          "dataMin" : [["195177600", "7407.899902", "0", "195177900", "7407.899902", "0", "195178200", "7408.000000", "0", "195178500", "7408.000000", "0", "195178800", "7408.000000", "0", "195179100", "7408.100098", "0", "195179400", "7408.100098", "0", "195179700", "7408.100098", "0", "195180000", "7408.200195", "0", "195180300", "7408.200195", "0", "195180600", "7408.200195", "0", "195180900", "7408.200195", "0"]]
        }, {
          "hour" : "1",
          "dataMin" : [["195181200", "7408.299805", "0", "195181500", "7408.299805", "0", "195181800", "7408.299805", "0", "195182100", "7408.399902", "0", "195182400", "7408.399902", "0", "195182700", "7408.399902", "0", "195183000", "7408.399902", "0", "195183300", "7408.500000", "0", "195183600", "7408.500000", "0", "195183900", "7408.500000", "0", "195184200", "7408.600098", "0", "195184500", "7408.600098", "0"]]
        }, {
          "hour" : "2",
          "dataMin" : [["195184800", "7408.600098", "0", "195185100", "7408.600098", "0", "195185400", "7408.700195", "0", "195185700", "7408.700195", "0", "195186000", "7408.700195", "0", "195186300", "7408.799805", "0", "195186600", "7408.799805", "0", "195186900", "7408.799805", "0", "195187200", "7408.899902", "0", "195187500", "7408.899902", "0", "195187800", "7408.899902", "0", "195188100", "7408.899902", "0"]]
        }, {
          "hour" : "3",
          "dataMin" : [["195188400", "7409.000000", "0", "195188700", "7409.000000", "0", "195189000", "7409.000000", "0", "195189300", "7409.100098", "0", "195189600", "7409.100098", "0", "195189900", "7409.100098", "0", "195190200", "7409.100098", "0", "195190500", "7409.200195", "0", "195190800", "7409.200195", "0", "195191100", "7409.200195", "0", "195191400", "7409.299805", "0", "195191700", "7409.299805", "0"]]
        }]
    }
```

the missing result is

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56df0865d23b548768ae4256"
        },
        "uniq_key": "last:HIS_AI:13:20:2016-3-9",
        "type": "last",
        "date": "2016-03-09",
        "channel_id": "13",
        "no_ai": "20",
        "zset": [
            {
                "hour": "0",
                "dataMin": [
                    [
                        "0"    //**bad value**
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "hour": "1",
                "dataMin": [
                    [
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "hour": "2",
                "dataMin": [
                    [
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

the java code is here

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("10.3.1.30");
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("energy");

    DBObject queryObj = new BasicDBObject();
    queryObj.put("channel_id", "13");
    queryObj.put("no_ai", "20");
    queryObj.put("date", "2016-03-09");

    DBObject result = db.getCollection("last").findOne(queryObj );
    System.out.println(result);
```

Help please!!!

Comment: There is no Java code here, can't help with a Java problem with no code. please post relevant Java code aswell

Comment: @Hughzi hi,i have post my java code.the mongo version is 2.6 and my java driver's version is 2.13.0. and i do a test to change the java driver to 2.14.0, it not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your `DBObject` you then put values into it using `DBObject.put()` this is correct.

the your call to `findOne()` will pull the first document out of your collection.

You need to use `db.getCollection("last").update(queryObj)` in order to save.

Comment: Is it unsuitable to update document before query it?

Comment: Someone  use node.js to query by same condition,the result is also missing some value.But use Mongodb visualization tools to query,the result is normal. Be crazy with it!!!

Comment: @stoneHah the find() function pulls the data out of the database. You create a local copy in DBObject then put values into it. then you pull out a new copy from the database. the two are separate.